# Reconnect to a server connection with websockets in python

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, server, python-asyncio

I am trying to use websockets library to create a connection with python. I need to establish the connection once and then tap into the same connection multiple times, each time with a different set of input arguments.
My requirement is to establish a connection once which will remain open through out the execution. Then, connect to the same established connection multiple times with different inputs.

I have the code as follows:

```
async def handler(websocket, test_info):
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(test_info))
    if not test_info:
       return
    async for message in websocket:
       if f"{message}" == "Benchmark Completed":
           websocket.keep_running = False
           asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
       else:
           print(message)

class App:
   async def connect_to_server(self, seq):
       uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
       async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
            await handler(websocket, seq)

  def start_app(self, data):
        start_server = websockets.serve(
            lambda websocket, path: handler(websocket, data), "localhost", 8765
        )
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
        ###Remaining code
```

Currently, the first time the connection is launched using `start_app` and handler is called. If `test_info` is empty, the execution doesn't return to execute the rest of the code. I believe using `run_forever` causes the execution to get stuck and never terminate. tried removing the same but in that case, the handler doesn't get invoked.

Also, if I call `connect_to_server` function to connect again, the same doesn't happen causing the execution to get stuck.